# Google compute engine php post request gives http 500 error

Tags: php, google-compute-engine

I'm really new in google cloud services and servers. I've successfully installed LAMP over SSH. However, when I try to post, get request over postman or application it always gives me 500 Internal Server Error. I wonder if there is a configuration that I missed? I do not know, maybe it is a problem with the port or maybe I should ho with App Engine instead of Compute Engine. I do not know what kind of document or code I should put here. In cases when you want I can share. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try to look at the web server's logs?

Comment: It sounds like your web server is returning 500 which is not necessarily related to GCE itself. Please provide more information such as logs, error description, or anything that can help the kind people here in SO to understand the real problem

Comment: this is my last log from last run @jabbson
`code`[Tue Dec 29 02:07:03.275501 2020] [php7:error] [pid 31906] [client 46.106.47.173:40319] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysqli_connect() in /var/www/html/api/config.php:4\nStack trace:\n#0 {main}\n  thrown in /var/www/html/api/config.php on line 4`code`
and my php.ini is too long to put here.  but i removed the semicolon from ;extension=mysqli

Comment: the php.ini file that i've edited in /etc/php/7.2/apache2 but I realized that there is another php.ini file located in /rtc/php/7.2/cli so should i edit that file as well?

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution from log file! thank you @jabbson :) I learn that is very important and helpful to check log files.

```
phpenmod mysqli
```

whit this command I've successfully activate extension and now it gives respond code 200. If someone will face this issue first -> check the apache2 log files, then-> don't forget to activate required plugins or extensions!